# Unable to identify the incorrect pin react-native-ble-plx

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ios, react-native-ble-plx

I am unable to catch the event that the user has entered a incorrect pin with pairing with BLE in iOS. In Android it clearly shows a message that incorrect pin is entered.
I am using the library react-native-ble-plx.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is this issue on github: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/823 It did not get many responses, I believe this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I understood that on catching the device.connect() error, the library returns an error object and the reason paramater has 'Authentication is insufficient' when the pin is incorrect. This value could be a catch for this use case.